# Login form in django3 using class base view

Tags: django, django-3.0, django-login

I am stuck in a class base login in Django 3 for last few hours

When I submit the user name and password it shows the following error

```
Using the URLconf defined in projectname.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='homepage']
signup/ [name='signup']
login/ [name='login']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
dashboard/
socialcard/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, login/post, didn’t match any of these.
```

URL Pattern path

```
    path("signup/", views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),

   path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

The View function

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class=UserCreationForm
    success_url=reverse_lazy('socialcard')
    template_name='registration/signup.html'
```

The settings files.

```
LOGIN_URL='login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='dashboard'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='homepage'
```

The signup model is working however the login model is showing the following error when I submit the form...

Here is the form call in the registration folder inside the template where the signup resides.

```
<form action="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{form}}
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "however the login model is showing the following error..." I think you missed something.

Comment: the login page shows up when I enter the user name and password it says that page not found... and gives that error

Comment: I see the error at the top of your question now. You also mention "the following error" towards the end of the question but then there is no error.

Comment: Also, you missed the most impartant part of the error message. There should be some lines above "Using the URLconf defined in projectname.urls,..." that tell you what route it attempted to use. This will give you the hint that leads to taha's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote action="post", which html will take it as a url where you point you form to go to after submit,

that's why it show this error

```
The current path, login/post, didn’t match any of these.
```

while what you need is to scpecify it as method, like below:

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{form}}
 <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

now, it should work as expected

Comment: Thanks, man... I was about to use the function-based view with too many if and else...